# Set text with line breaks to HTML from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string that has line breaks at the end of each line like the one I have below:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

This is from a string variable which I want to set to a paragraph tag in HTML. I tried using the innerHTML method but it only printed my results without the line breaks.

Any idea on how I can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace all the newlines with `<br>`s:

```js
const str = `1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1`;
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the paragraph's [`white-space` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to `pre`, `pre-wrap`, or `pre-line`. All will preserve line breaks.

```js
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = `1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1`;
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```